# Python renaming triggers error; file is being used by another process

Tags: windows, python-2.7, rename

I"m getting the following error message, and I can't figure out why renaming is trigger this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\make hypertext list from directory aaa.py", line 17, in 
    os.rename(fullname, nufullname)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import os
dir_path = r'E:\ddelete'
dir_list = os.listdir(dir_path)

html_file = r"E:\ddelete\AAA__ReadMeFirst___dirlist.html"
text_file = open(html_file, "w")
i = 10000
for item in sorted(dir_list):
    fullname = os.path.join(dir_path,item)
    ext = ext = os.path.splitext(fullname)[1]
    nufullname = os.path.join(dir_path, str(i) + ext)
    nufilename = str(i) + ext
    print fullname
    print nufullname
    os.rename(fullname, nufullname)
    temp_item = '''<a href="./''' + nufilename + '''">''' + item + '</a><br />' + '\r\n'
    text_file.write(temp_item)
    i += 1

text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I was attempting to rename the html_file to which I was writing text.
I'm sorry for wasting your time.
                Marc